# Make [gmpl] a synonym of [mathprog]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751086/operational-research-applied-to-scrum-using-solver-studio-gmpl-golfarelli-me) about GMPL today.

It [looks like](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/GMPL_%28MathProg%29) GMPL is another name for GNU MathProg (we have this tag: [mathprog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathprog)). Quote from there:

> MathProg can also be referred to as GMPL (GNU Mathematical Programming
>   Language), the two terms being interchangeable.

To prevent confusion, I suggest to create a synonym: [gmpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmpl) -> [mathprog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathprog).
Also, [gnu-mathprog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-mathprog) -> [mathprog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathprog) would be helpful too.